# AWS CloudFormation Overlapping CIDR

Tags: amazon-web-services, debugging, aws-cloudformation

I have just started working with AWS Cloudformation. I was trying to create a stack that routes traffic from my internet gateway to my NLB and subsequently to an instance in a target group. Unfortunately, I keep getting this error message from my stack events for the MyRouteTableAssociation resource I get this error message

> Resource handler returned message: "Route table contains unsupported route destination. The unsupported route destination is less specific than or non-overlapping with VPC local CIDR. (Service: Ec2, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 312fc883-6f1e-4cf3-8e90-87bf386ae819)" (RequestToken: cc0f8b6e-dfb0-4576-f2c8-c3456cd38b74, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)

my cloudformation template

```
Resources:
  MyVPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: "174.10.12.0/24"
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      Tags:
        - Key: "Name"
          Value: "TestVPC"

  PrivateSubnet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      # AvailabilityZone: "us-east-1a"
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [0, !GetAZs "us-east-1"]
      CidrBlock: "174.10.12.0/25"
      VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
      Tags:
        - Key: "Name"
          Value: "PrivateSubnet"

  PublicSubnet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      # AvailabilityZone: "us-east-1b"
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [1, !GetAZs "us-east-1"]
      CidrBlock: "174.10.12.128/25"
      VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
      Tags:
        - Key: "Name"
          Value: "PublicSubnet"

  TestInternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: TestIGW
  
  AttachGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref TestInternetGateway

  MyRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: TestRT

  InternetRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: AttachGateway
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref MyRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: '0.0.0.0/0'
      GatewayId: !Ref TestInternetGateway

  MyRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::GatewayRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      GatewayId: !Ref TestInternetGateway
      RouteTableId: !Ref MyRouteTable

  MySubnetRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref MyRouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet

  NLBAPIInstanceSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Allow Access from InternetGateway
      VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          DestinationSecurityGroupId: !Ref TestInstanceSecurityGroup

  TestInstanceSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Allow Access from Network Load Balancer
      VpcId: !Ref MyVPC

  TestInstanceGroupIngress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: !Ref TestInstanceSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: 80
      ToPort: 80
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref NLBAPIInstanceSecurityGroup

  MyLoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Type: network
      Scheme: internal
      Subnets:
        - !Ref PrivateSubnet
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: TestNLB

  MyLoadBalancerListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: forward
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref MyTargetGroup
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref MyLoadBalancer
      Port: 80
      Protocol: TCP

  MyTestInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-0230bd60aa48260c6
      KeyName: Lala
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - AssociatePublicIpAddress: true
          SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet
          DeviceIndex: 0
          GroupSet:
            - !Ref TestInstanceSecurityGroup
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: TestEc2Instance
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash
          yum update -y
          yum install httpd -y
          systemctl start httpd
          systemctl enable httpd
          echo "<html><h1>Hello from $(hostname -f)</h1></html>" > /var/www/html/index.html

  MyTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 30
      HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 5
      HealthyThresholdCount: 2
      Matcher:
        HttpCode: 200
      Name: TestTargetGroup
      Port: 80
      Protocol: TCP
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 2
      TargetType: instance
      Targets:
        - Id: !Ref MyTestInstance
          Port: 80
      VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: TestTargetGroup

Outputs:
  VPCID:
    Description: Output VPCs ID
    Value: !Ref MyVPC
  PublicSubnetID:
    Description: Output Public Subnet ID
    Value: !Ref PublicSubnet
  PrivateSubnetID:
    Description: Output Public Subnet ID
    Value: !Ref PrivateSubnet
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MyRouteTableAssociation` is not needed since you are using `InternetRoute`. So **remove** `MyRouteTableAssociation` resource.